# Ubuntu Software

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, permissions, software-center

I'm new to Ubuntu, but the Software app will not launch. When I open a terminal window and navigate to: /usr/bin/ubuntu-software .... I do see  it's there, but it will not launch. Can anyone please advise what I should do? 
Thanks!

```
/usr/bin$ ubuntu-software
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
(ubuntu-software:5299): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_dir_read_name: assertion 'dir != NULL' failed
(ubuntu-software:5299): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/gnome-software/featured-gimp.png': Error opening file: Too many open files
(ubuntu-software:5299): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you trying to open ubuntu software center?

Comment: yes - I am trying to open the ubuntu software center

Comment: It opens and then closes within a few seconds

Comment: Open the terminal and type 'software-center' and press enter. See what happens..

Comment: I did ... the original  post shows the failure message from the terminal window.  It tries to open and I see the window but then closes

Comment: This is the error log that I see from the terminal window when it launches that way.

Comment: Sorry had to break up the log into several post ... too many charaters.... the final post shows there is a core dump

Comment: @DavidSchroeder Next time click the  `Edit` button below your question and paste the messages there. Then highlight the screen messages and click the braces button `{}` to convert it to code format for easy ready and scrolling.

Comment: @DavidSchroeder Note that I have trimmed your "posted error logs" from the comments as it clutters up the comments section and is very (very( hard to read - please post the error logs as an ***edit to your question***.

Comment: I suggest that you try another method or tool to install programs. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/885453/16-04-software-download-stuck-pending/887084#887084

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment yet due to rep.

Maybe you already found a workaround but this is a reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573453/comments/10),
There is a workaround detailed in post #10:

1. Download the archive according to your version https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gnome-software
2. as an adm remove the original gs-plugins-9
3. extract the recently downloaded gs-plugins-9 file
4. as adm move it to the right place (usr/lib/)