# Flash Installation issues

Tags: apt, flash, 16.10

My PC is a Dell approximately 7-8 years old running Ubuntu 16.10

I have watched tutorials on youtube and tried to install the ubuntu restricted extras to help make the install a bit easier to no avail.

When i type in the command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It tells me to enter my password then nothing happens.

Can you help - How to install some type of flash on my desktop computer?

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) shows how you can install `adobe-flashplugin`. With that you get flash for both Firefox and Chromium/Opera/Vivaldi.

Comment: So do you enter the password?

Comment: I went to software & updates. I then went to "Other Software" & entered the command deb http://cononical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner so I could update my software. once i go thru the whole process it tells me the software is out of date & I have to reload the page. it proceeds as if its trying to update only to tell me that i need to check my internet connection (which is fine) & in the details says E:repository http://canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety release has no release file. and now i cant open my software & updates at all.. im lost

Comment: i entered the command from below in my terminal (restricted extras command) now says unable to lock download directory...mind you this is the 2nd time ive tried to install. i also followed the link you provided below and couldnt get those to work. i have ubuntu 16.10. i noticed it said for ubuntu 16.04...that matter right?

Comment: it now says i have to manually run the dpkg to install. im just gonna uninstall ubuntu and go back to windows. installing a flash should not be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window you type (or copy & paste) the following command line

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Then there is a prompt to enter your password (the same one as you use to log in to your user account). This assumes that you have superuser privileges. Otherwise you are not allowed to install programs like this. I get the following prompt, and you get a prompt for *your* user ID.

```
[sudo] password for sudodus:
```

There is no echo (no stars, nothing) when you enter your password, but it is read anyway, so

- enter your password
- and finish with the Enter key.

Then things start to happen. (I have an up to date version of lubuntu-restricted-extras, so I get the following output.)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (65).
```

**Edit:** After writing the answer, I saw your latest comment. I suggest that you try to repair your system according to the following link (the tips using command lines)

[askubuntu.com/questions/885453/16-04-software-download-stuck-pending 'From the command line'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885453/16-04-software-download-stuck-pending/887084#887084)